# VGA led stays red but everything works fine

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, post

I have a computer with a Asus Z87-A C2 motherboard and an nVidia GTX 970 connected to a screen using DVI. Up until now everything worked fine.

Recently I have switched to a DisplayPort screen.

Around the same time, I have started to notice that from time to time the VGA POST LED on the motherboard stays lit after the POST sequence, meaning that there is something wrong with the graphic card. But everything works fine, the led staying red seems to be the only symptom.

Also if I reboot the computer, the led will turn off after POST (as it is supposed to be when there is no issue detected during POST). And the issue seems to manifest itself more after a cold boot.

I am looking for any plausible cause or any mean to get some diagnostic data (to check the GPU or motherboard status for instance).

### EDIT

I have confirmed that the LED stays on when the screen is turned off. When the screen is just in "sleep mode", the LED will turn off after POST. My screen will turn itself off after 4h of sleep that's why I thought of cold boot issues.

Also the LED will stay red when there are no video cable plugged in the PC. Weirdly enough my previous screen plugged using DVI even turned off was enough not prevent the LED from staying on.

Comment: Interesting question but the answer is probably "that's how it works, that's how it has been designed". Some BIOS/UEFI upgrade may or may not change the behavior.

Comment: @MichaelBay The POST leds on the motherboard are supposed to turn on and off during POST. They are only supposed to stay on if there is a problem detected. So the fact that the VGA led stays lit means that something is wrong with the graphic card. There are lot of people on the Internet complaining of POST leds staying lit, but this is generally associated with a failure to boot and the leds are here to help find the issue. In my case there are no visible issues if it wasn't for the led.

Comment: *In my case there are no visible issues* then it's not a big problem, is it? I suggest you ask ASUS directly and/or update UEFI if there's an update available.

Comment: @MichaelBay I didn't say it was a big problem, but the presence of a warning sign that generally means that there are issues critical enough to prevent a PC from booting can be concerning to some extent. Already checked for UEFI updates.